# Bathroom sink valve drip

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, waterproofing, shutoff

**Issue:** The cold water shut off valve in my bathroom sink has developed a slow drip over the past week. It fills up a medium sized bucket in the span of about a day. The drip seems to be coming from either the nut connecting to the wall pipe or the nut connecting to the mesh tube.

**Attempts to fix:** I've tried the following multiple times in order to correct the drip...

- Teflon tape
- Permatex thread sealant

**New issue:** Now for some reason the hot and cold water to this sink no longer work. I have confirmed the valves under the sink are in their on positions and the drip is still present, so water is getting up to the sink. Just not through the line. I could understand something having happened with the cold line due to my attempts to correct it's drip, but the hot line not working doesn't make any sense to me. To confirm, I have not touched the hot line other than to turn it on and off at the valve under the sink.

Any thoughts as to what may have happened before I call a plumber out during a pandemic in winter?

I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I presume the drip is from the spout, but you don't specify that in your question. Because faucets can drip/leak from various places, would you please edit that detail into your question? Or perhaps you are talking about the *water supply stop-valves*, which are usually under/behind the sink?

Comment: Apologies, it is actually in the cold water valve under the sink. It seems to originate in the connecting nuts that go into the wall or up to the mesh line. I will edit my question to include it.

Comment: Think it is not the nuts but either the part the nut seat on or the shut off valve itself.  Would remove the faucet strainer and see if it is blocked.  Hot water tanks are known to develop hard water sediment that can block faucet strainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the valve itself to retape the main line connection, I discovered the valve itself had a pressure crack down the back side of it. This is the cause of the leak. Replacing the valve should correct the issue no sweat.